# JSP import cannot be resolved in Tomcat 5.5.27

Tags: jsp, tomcat, import, compilation

I am receiving the following error when navigating to a certain page in our Tomcat web application:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/ecrs].[jsp]] -     <Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception>
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
The import com.nag.ecrs.domain.model cannot be resolved
```

The import statement looks like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.nag.ecrs.domain.model.ModelHelper"%>
```

According to [Failing import in on-the-fly JSP compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412906/failing-import-in-on-the-fly-jsp-compilation) , it seems the compiler is tripping up because we have a package named:

```
com.nag.ecrs.domain.model
```

and a class named:

```
com.nag.ecrs.domain.Model
```

We indeed have the class com.nag.ecrs.domain.Model with the upper case 'M'. If I were to remove the import and use the fully qualified class name com.nag.ecrs.domain.model.ModelHelper, it works. However it's not a neat solution. The solution in the above link was to rename the package, which we also don't want to do.

This is only affecting me, the page displays fine for my 2 other colleagues in their environments.

So my question is, what is causing the JSP compiler to fail when using a package where that package name also exists as class? And how can this be fixed?

I've tried:

- cleaning/rebuilding web app
- installing new Tomcat
- setting the allowLinking context switch in Tomcat to false

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:435)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:965)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:600)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.rating.specialisedLending_jsp._jspService(specialisedLending_jsp.java:2989)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:965)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:600)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ecrsMain_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f10(ecrsMain_jsp.java:695)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ecrsMain_jsp._jspService(ecrsMain_jsp.java:276)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:302)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at com.nag.ecrs.authentication.PostLoginFilter.doFilter(PostLoginFilter.java:66)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at com.nag.ecrs.authentication.CreateUserFilter.doFilter(CreateUserFilter.java:65)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: What environment are you in? Does your filesystem use case-insensitive file names? Are you running from an exploded-WAR-directory, or a WAR file?

Comment: Windows XP, from an exploded war directory. Good point on case sensitivity, will check the ObCaseInsensitive registry setting and report back.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ObCaseInsensitive was set to 1 (case insensitive). I tried setting it to 0 and rebooting, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version of Tomcat: 5.5.x is scheduled to reach end-of-life on 30 September 2012 ( http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-55-eol.html) which is not far off.

The later versions of Tomcat use more recent versions of the Eclipse Java Compiler which may not suffer from this particular problem. I would recommend going all the way up to Tomcat 7, as the pain of upgrading from 5.5 to 7.0 is no more than going from 5.5 to 6.0. Also, Tomcat 7.0 has some really great improvements over Tomcat 6 that are very unlikely to ever be back-ported.

Comment: Yes we'd love to, but there should be a reason for the behaviour described

Comment: The reason is apparently that Tomcat 5.5.27 uses a version of EJC that can't handle this situation. Consider asking the Eclipse team why their compiler objects to these kinds of imports.

Comment: I get the same problem with Tomcat 6 on a Mac (with a case-insensitive filesystem). This uses ECJ 3.7 which still seems to not cope properly.

Comment: I'm not sure that the case-insensitive filesystem would make a difference, here, because it would be looking for a directory for the package and not for SomeClass.class.